# issue with connecting data in databricks from data lake and reading JSON into Folium

Tags: json, pyspark, azure-blob-storage, folium

i'm working on something based of this blogpost:

https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html#Getting-Started
specifically part 13 - using Cloropleth maps:

the piece of code they use is the following:

```
import pandas as pd

url = (
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-visualization/folium/master/examples/data"
)
state_geo = f"{url}/us-states.json"
state_unemployment = f"{url}/US_Unemployment_Oct2012.csv"
state_data = pd.read_csv(state_unemployment)

m = folium.Map(location=[48, -102], zoom_start=3)

folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=state_geo,
    name="choropleth",
    data=state_data,
    columns=["State", "Unemployment"],
    key_on="feature.id",
    fill_color="YlGn",
    fill_opacity=0.7,
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name="Unemployment Rate (%)",
).add_to(m)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)

m
```

if I use this I get the requested map.

Now I try to do this with my own data; i work in databricks

so I have a JSON with the GEOJSON data (source_file1) and a CSV file (source_file2) with the data that needs to be "plotted" on the map.

```
source_file1 = "dbfs:/mnt/sandbox/MAARTEN/TOPO/Belgie_GEOJSON.JSON"
state_geo = spark.read.json(source_file1,multiLine=True)

source_file2 = "dbfs:/mnt/sandbox/MAARTEN/TOPO/DATASVZ.csv" 
df_2 =  spark.read.format("CSV").option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "true").option("delimiter",";").load(source_file2)
state_data = df_2.toPandas()
```

when adjusting the code below:

```
m = folium.Map(location=[48, -102], zoom_start=3)

folium.Choropleth(
  geo_data=state_geo,
  name="choropleth",
  data=state_data,
  columns=["State", "Unemployment"],
  key_on="feature.properties.name_nl",
  fill_color="YlGn",
  fill_opacity=0.7,
  line_opacity=0.2,
  legend_name="% Marktaandeel CC",
).add_to(m)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)

m
```

So i upload the geo_data parameter as a Sparkdatafram, I get the following error:

````
ValueError: Cannot render objects with any missing geometries: DataFrame[features: array<struct<geometry:struct<coordinates:array<array<array<string>>>,type:string>,properties:struct<arr_fr:string,arr_nis:bigint,arr_nl:string,fill:string,fill-opacity:double,name_fr:string,name_nl:string,nis:bigint,population:bigint,prov_fr:string,prov_nis:bigint,prov_nl:string,reg_fr:string,reg_nis:string,reg_nl:string,stroke:string,stroke-opacity:bigint,stroke-width:bigint>,type:string>>, type: string]```
````

I think it is because transforming the data from the "blob format" in the Azure datalake to the sparkdataframe, something goes wrong with the format. I tested this in a jupyter notebook from my desktop, data straight from file to folium and it all works.

If i load it directly from the source, like the example does with their webpage, so i adjust the 'geo_data' parameter for the folium function:

```
m = folium.Map(location=[48, -102], zoom_start=3)

folium.Choropleth(
  geo_data=source_file1,     #this gets adjusted directly to data lake
  name="choropleth",
  data=state_data,
  columns=["State", "Unemployment"],
  key_on="feature.properties.name_nl",
  fill_color="YlGn",
  fill_opacity=0.7,
  line_opacity=0.2,
  legend_name="% Marktaandeel CC",
).add_to(m)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)

m
```

I get the error

```
Use "/dbfs", not "dbfs:": The function expects a local file path. The error is caused by passing a path prefixed with "dbfs:".
```

So I started wondering what is the difference between my JSON file and the one of the blogpost. And the only thing i can imagine is that the Azure datalake doesn't store my json as a json but as a block blob file and for some reason i am not converting it properly so that folium can read it.

[Azure blob storage (data lake)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgeBb.png)

So can someone with folium knowledge let me know if
A. it is not possible to load the geo_data directly from a datalake ?
B. in what format I need to upload the data ?

any thoughts on this would be helpfull!!!

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this issue, just had to replace "dbfs:" with "/dbfs". I tried it a lot of times but used "/dbfs:" and got another error.

can't believe i'm this stupid :-)